# Calling props function inside component's function "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a button that triggers my onClick function:

`<button id="closeModal" variant="danger" onClick={ this.onClick }></button>`

My onClick is binded in constructor:

`this.onClick = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`

And then I'm specifying the function to call two functions: one of them is from props and one is not (it's Formik's function).

```
onClick(event) {
    this.handleSubmit.bind(this, values);
    this.props.closeModal;
}
```

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined` is the same for both functions in onClick, when I'm switching them to places. I want the button to trigger two functions now. Before, when I had only

`<button id="closeModal" variant="danger" onClick={ this.props.closeModal }></button>`

everything was ok. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: this.handleSubmit.bind(this, values) what is values here btw bind returns a new function, you need to store that function inside a variable then call it. You are binding that in constructor and again you are binding inside onClick. Can you add full code?

Comment: Can you please add the complete component code here?

Comment: @vijayscode values are array of my form values from user. Thank you for your advice! I'll keep that in mind in further function declaring. And about my question - everything is ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you you are not binding the correct function based on your code i expect to see something like this

`this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)`

instead of

`this.onClick = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)`

Also you need to call `closeModal` so it should be

`this.props.closeModal();`

Comment: Stupid mistake... I got confused in all Formik's functions and all these bindings. Many thank for pointing this mistake and thank you for showing how to call props function, I didn't do it in such way before

Answer (score 0):

Change in your constructor, then check...

from

`this.onClick = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`

to

`this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);`

Comment: yes, thank you! I marked as answer post before yours, because @Amr Labib also showed me how to use my props function inside another function